# Web3: current best practice to connect Metamask to Chrome?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I am currently trying to connect my React front-end to Metamask on Chrome.

When using the following method, I get that `ethereum.enable()` is deprecated:

```js
if (window.ethereum) {
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    window.ethereum.enable();
}
```

To be more accurate, the complete warning is:

```
MetaMask: 'ethereum.enable()' is deprecated and may be removed in the future. Please use the 'eth_requestAccounts' RPC method instead.
For more information, see: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1102
```

---

So I when to the documentation and updated that code to:

```js
if (window.ethereum) {
    try {
        // Request account access if needed
        const accounts = await window.ethereum.send(
            "eth_requestAccounts"
        );
        setError(null);
    } catch (error) {
        setError("Unable to connect to Metamask");
    }
}
```

This way, I get the following warning:

```js
MetaMask: 'ethereum.send(...)' is deprecated and may be removed in the future. Please use 'ethereum.sendAsync(...)' or 'ethereum.request(...)' instead.
For more information, see: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193
```

Subsidiary question: I still don't really understand why I need to set this async function call in a variable (`accounts`), so... If someone has an explanation, I'm taking it!

---

Anyway: after this warning, I went to the doc again and I saw that `sendAsync` is supposed to be deprecated as well... And I didn't find anything about `ethereum.request`.

TLDR: what is the current best practice to connect Metamask to a front-end, right now? Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now that `window.web` and `ethereum.enable()` are deprecated, the recommended way to connect to MetaMask is with `ethereum.request()`. The function takes an object with a JSON-RPC method (like `eth_requestAccounts`) and returns a Promise.

For example:

```js
if (window.ethereum) {
  try {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
    setAccounts(accounts);
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code === 4001) {
      // User rejected request
    }

    setError(error);
  }
}
```

You can find full documentation here: https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#basic-usage